# How to make a funcion in C++ which read from a file to an array of hex?

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

First of all I must to say that i'm total noob in C++ programing.
I have to make this funcion:

`void License(bool& exists, unsigned int longLicense, unsigned int license[])`

It has to read a txt file which contains 6 hex numbers separated by "-", for example:

> 462E3784-11F24312-13B57611-27A3197F-3B30158A-AB7EF8E0

and then save this numbers (in decimal) in the "license" array. Also it has to return true or false in "exists".

I've tried doing it like this but it doesn't work. It reads correctly only the first number. The rest of them aren't the same as I have in the txt file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define N_INT_LICENSE 6

using namespace std;

bool existe;
unsigned int licencia[N_INT_LICENSE];

ifstream stream;
stream.open("license.txt");
if (stream) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N_INT_LICENSE; i++) {
        stream >> hex >> licencia[i];
    }
```

I didn't find other topic that could help me but if there is one I'm sorry for posting that.
Please someone help me.
Thank you.

Comment: `void License(bool& exists, unsigned int longLicense, unsigned int license[])` is invalid in c, so it's just c++ don't mix the languages please. Also, there is no such thing as array of `HEX`, hex is just a representation, so just remove the `hex` in `stream >> ...` unless you want to store the hexadecimal representation of the bytes.

Comment: Your attempt does not work because you ignore the `-` characters, even though you acknowledge them in your problem description.

Comment: @iharob: He needs `std::hex` to *read* a hexadecimal representation. His code is correct with regards to usage of that manipulator.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I just meant that it wasn't clear what `hex` means... in this context, because with all due respect to the OP, they might not know what hex is.

Comment: My answer below ignores the '-'s and works fine.  So, could you be more specific about what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

You should skip the dash:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N_INT_LICENSE; i++) {
    stream >> hex >> licencia[i];
    if (i!= N_INT_LICENSE-1) {
        char c; 
        stream >> c; 
        if (c!='-') 
           cout<<"Error: invalid format";
    }
}
```

By the way,  what shall happen if the license key is too short ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. How ever could you explain to me how you ignore the "-" character with `if (i!= N_INT_LICENSE-1)`. I don't understand it.

Comment: Sure! The condition makes sure we skip the dash except for the very last number you are reading. The core of the if block is to read a single char and make sure it's a dash